# Replace certain characters from many txt files within a folder

Tags: windows-7, batch

I have many txt files inside a folder and I want to replace/remove some characters in them. I want to remove "{", "}", and want to replace "*^" by "E" (here *^ has to be together).

Is there a way to do this in a batch? I am now doing one by one which is really time consuming. I am using Windows 7.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you mentioned "batch" simply because you're looking for a way to automate this and thought a batch file might be the best solution. Well it isn't, so unless you specifically *need* to use a batch file (in which case I'll modify/delete this answer), use a better tool for the job instead such as Notepad++ (or any other comparable full-featured text editor):

[image: 1]

There are *many* other programs whose sole job is text search/replace, for example [grepWin](https://code.google.com/p/grepwin):

[image: 2]